# Prisma stored procedure call does not returns keys

Tags: mysql, express, prisma

I have a stored procedure in mysql which does a select query against some tables. I am executing this stored procedure using prisma raw querycall producer_name(${input}). Response from prisma does not have key name instead it look like this

```
[{
f0: 123,
f1: "fistname",
f2: "lastname"
}]
```

Instead of field name I am getting f0, f1 & f2 etc. Is this the internal design of prisma, or am I doing anything wrong here.

I am using prisma client 3.10.0
I have executed this and found the same issue. below is the response I got from the prisma client

```
[
    {
        "f0": 1,
        "f1": "first name",
        "f2": "last_name"
    }
]
```

and query is

```
prisma.$queryRaw`call db_schema_name.test_procedure();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this GitHub Discussion: [#12312](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/12312), there are other users who have reported the same issue.

As recommended in the discussion if you could create a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.yml) with a minimal reproduction then the team could investigate this.